# How to handle non default_constructible tyname variables

Tags: c++, c++17

My question to you is how can someone handle a non default_constructible variable. I came upon this question on a test I had and got me thinking. Please find the below example to fully understand:

```
template<typename W>
class Foo {
  array<W> arr;
public:
  void fooFunc(W const& value){
     // I wanted to do the below assignment which seemed to be the wrong thing
     for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
     {
        arr[i] = value;
     }
  }
};
```

From the above code I was told that line `arr[i] = value;` was invalid since I assumed that value was default constructible. So my question is, how could I have handled this case?

--EDIT 1--
Also I would like if you could recommend me any resources in order to improve my c++ skills. Any books, tutorials etc would be excelent

Comment: `arr[i] = value;` is not affected by the type of `arr[i]` being default-constructible.

Comment: If `array` is `std::array` then it needs a *size*.

Comment: As for the assignment loop, unless you go out of bounds then it's okay. Default-construction of the objects in the array happens at `Foo<W>` construction.

Comment: You have to know how you want the variables **initialized**.  One possible answer is that you want to copy-construct them from the `value` parameter (for which Marshall supplied one solution), but that assignment could also be unrelated.

Comment: @DavisHerring How could I have copy-constructed it, could you please provide a couple of examples in order to understand better? Thank you all for your answers as well!

Comment: @harisiad: Marshall already explained that.  You seem not to understand the answer yet, but this isn’t the right forum to explain the basics of constructing objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::array<W>` will not compile, because it needs two template parameters.

`std::array<W, 2>` (for example) will create a variable containing two default-constructed values of type `W`. If `W` is not default-constructible, this will fail to compile.

The following psuedo-code will make a `vector` containing two elements of type `W`, even if `W` is not default constructible.

```
std::vector<W> v;
v.emplace_back(/* some parameters used to construct a W*/);
v.emplace_back(/* some parameters used to construct another W*/);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! What do you mean parameters used to construct W? Could you please provide me with some examples? Maybe a couple of different types in order to fully understand?

Answer (score 2):

In your code, if you intent to define a non-static data member of a type of a specialization of class template std::array, you should declare it as the following:

```cpp
#include <array>
template<typename W,std::size_t N>
class Foo {
  std::array<W,N> arr;
public:
  void fooFunc(W const& value){
     for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
     {
        arr[i] = value;
     }
  }
};
```

It will be ok.